# How to convert json to java script array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the json string like,

```
string js=[{"Name":"Pini","ID":"111"},

{"Name":"Yaniv","ID":"123"},

{"Name":"Yoni","ID":"145"}]
```

And I need to convert this into like the following format using java script.

```
[['Pini',111],['Yaniv',123],['Yoni',145]]
```

How to convert the json string into javascript array using javascript function?

Comment: Since you're using jquery, you should try $.parseJSON() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: why the downvotes? jquery was one of the tags on the question :/

Comment: I was downvoted as well, for my proposed solution, without any explanation. Other users were also downvoted. This is not fair.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this:

```
var ret = [];

for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
    ret.push([js[i].Name, js[i].ID]);
}

// ret holds your array of arrays
```

Or something like:

```
var ret = $.map(js, function (el, i) {
    return [[el.Name, el.ID]];
});
```

An example of both: http://jsfiddle.net/RNY8M/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

### [**JsFiddler Demo of below code**](http://jsfiddle.net/zZsW6/)

```
var JSONObject = {"results":[{"Name":"Pini","ID":"111"},
                  {"Name":"Yaniv","ID":"123"},
                             {"Name":"Yoni","ID":"145"}]};


var Users= [];

$.each(JSONObject.results, function(i, obj)
       {
    alert(obj.Name);
    alert(obj.ID);
    Users.push([obj.Name, obj.ID]);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of transformations I always prefer using **[UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org)** which is an **utility-belt library** (mainly for object/array transformations) for Javascript. I think that it provides great functions that make life **easier**, allowing javascript developers to be **more productive** and to achieve a **better legibility** for the resulting code.

Here is the solution with underscore (extended):

```
var js=[{"Name":"Pini","ID":"111"},  
        {"Name":"Yaniv","ID":"123"},    
        {"Name":"Yoni","ID":"145"}]

var names = _.pluck(js, 'Name');
var ids = _.pluck(js, 'ID');

var result = _.zip(names, ids)
```

And you achive the desired result:

```
[['Pini',111],['Yaniv',123],['Yoni',145]]
```

**Solution in one line** with underscorejs:

```
var result = _.zip(_.pluck(js, 'Name'), _.pluck(js, 'ID'))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't understand why somebody downvoted my answer here. This is a correct answer (anyone can test it in the console), I'm usign a well known javascript library, and it solves the problem the users asked about, showing research effort. It's completely unfair to downvote in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I correct my solution, I hadn't read well the specs (my fault):

```
var jsonArray = [{"Name":"Pini","ID":"111"}, {"Name":"Yaniv","ID":"123"}, {"Name":"Yoni","ID":"145"}];

var jsonConverted = {};
$(jsonArray).each( function() {
    jsonConverted.push([ this.Name, this.ID ]);
});
```

This solution uses jQuery.

Comment: Someone likes to downvote, without explanation or discussion. If a solution seems not appropriate, maybe leaving a comment could be more professional.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that will work for a *simple* object (not deep objects, though.... but I'll leave that for you to implement).

http://jsfiddle.net/eUtkC/

```
var js = [{
    "Name": "Pini",
    "ID": "111"},
{
    "Name": "Yaniv",
    "ID": "123"},
{
    "Name": "Yoni",
    "ID": "145"}]

function obj2arr(obj) {
    var i, key, length = obj.length,
        aOutput = [],
        aObjValues;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        aObjValues = [];
        for (key in obj[i]) {
            if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                aObjValues.push(obj[i][key]);
            }
        }
        aOutput.push(aObjValues);
    }
    return aOutput;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj2arr(js)))​
```

**EDIT**

Here's a version using `Array.prototype.map`:

http://jsfiddle.net/eUtkC/1/

```
function obj2arr(obj) {
    var key, aOutput = [];
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            aOutput.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return aOutput;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(js.map(obj2arr)))​
```

Comment: Why the downvote?... I gave the OP TWO copy-paste solutions to the problem =0\

Comment: I was downvoted as well, without explanation! All good solutions, by the way.